# Database Sharing for Android and Website

Tags: android, web

i want to build one app which can upload data to the website database. Now i using XAMPP for my android database. How to upload data from android to the website database? Can i use XAMPP as well? Thanks

Regards,
YY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend creating a PHP RESTful web service that connects to your MySQL database.
Transferring your data in a JSON format is the most common way, depending on what you have to upload.
There are several ways to call the web service in Android. You could go basic and use a HttpUrlConnection to do the job, or use libraries such as [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). Just remember to run web service calls (or any network process) in a different thread by using an IntentService, Service, AsyncTask (watch out, [pitfalls](http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2013/04/the-dark-side-of-asynctask.html)), AsyncTaskLoader, etc...

Don't forget to check out [this on the Developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) as well.